# Why getAll method of Guava LoadingCache returns different types of ImmutableMap?

Tags: java, google-guava-cache

I have simple Guava LoadingCache use case where I pass list of key objects to `getAll` and implemented `loadAll` to get results when not available in cache.

The problem is When cache is empty,

- Calling `getAll` for collection of records returns Map of type `RegularImmutableMap`.
- And calling `getAll` for collection of **single record** returns Map of type `SingletonImmutableBiMap`.

This eventually leads to another problem. When I try to collect `map.values()` on it, `RegularImmutableMap` returns a type of `ImmutableList` and `SingletonImmutableBiMap` returns a type of `ImmutableSet`.

From user perspective is there any specific reason/advantage why `getAll` method returns different types of `ImmutableMap`?

Comment: in both cases it returns ImmutableMap which content can not be changed, so why are you concern about if single element is contained in list or set?

Comment: Exactly my question, why same API should return different data structures based on just number of elements in input collection. Obvious disadvantage is user has to perform type checks before sharing it further and send uniform results to their caller. In this case I can send underlying `ImmutableCollection` but delegates type checks to caller. At least to me this do not sound clean unless there is any design principle which allows to do so with added advantage. This is what I am looking for, Since same API shares different result to users `What advantage it gives to users to get List or Set`?.

Comment: But why to check underlying type? Part of the contract is only `ImmutableCollection` type. Underlying implementation can be changed anytime in future. That's why interfaces are used - to hide implementation details. From user perspective you just need to read values (as collection is immutable), nothing more. If you need to perform some other operations that depends on specific data-structure e.g. fast access of values, just put all elements of `ImmutableCollection` in whatever structure you want. For example `ArrayList<>(immutableCollection);`

Comment: You are absolutely correct but this question should be asked to `getAll` method :) . Why not send `ImmutableCollection`? Why do you break contract and share List or Set. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong here.

Comment: `ImmutableMap#values()` returns in both cases `ImmutableCollection` (both `ImmutableSet` and `ImmutableList` implements `ImmutableCollection` interface so they share the same behaviour which is part of the contract. The same applies for method `LoadingCache#getAll()`.

Comment: Suppose you would downcast returned collection based on implementation details (digged from source-code). In future release of guava library, `LoadingCache#getAll()` will return  some new `ImmutableMap` implementation. This way you would get an `ClassCastException`. You can rely only on returned type, which should be sufficient for your usage

Comment: But why to risk exception by downcasting to concrete implementation type when both types guarantee the same behaviour i. e. implements `ImmutableMap` so you can perform immutable map operations. Both provide behaviour which you will expect from ImmutableMap. Functionality is the same (even if they differ on implementation level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this has nothing to do with `Cache` - the `LocalCache` implementation you're presumably using simply [calls `ImmutableMap.copyOf()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fd919e5/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L4027) before returning the collected results.

So your underlying question is really *why does [`ImmutableMap.of(K, V)` return an `ImmutableBiMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/fd919e5/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.java#L123)?*

This has been the behavior [since 2012](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/783fca80052b1be76ca83150f982eeabfbc821f8) and the short answer is because `ImmutableBiMap` extends `ImmutableMap`, therefore there's no need to have both a `SingletonImmutableMap` and `SingletonImmutableBiMap` implementation.

As matoni has said, [`ImmutableMap.values()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#values--) returns an `ImmutableCollection`, therefore you cannot rely on a particular implementation to return an `ImmutableList` or an `ImmutableSet` (or some other mysterious type that extends `ImmutableCollection`). Not only that, you cannot rely on the existing behavior staying this way! For a brief while (from [February](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/cac2e34369fe1b6b71ef0006e6fc50766fee8147) to [June](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/729592303fde5f9ce2a7ec2aaeb558c62601a64b)) `ImmutableMap` actually didn't use `ImmutableBiMap`.

This means you should not expect `ImmutableMap.values()` to return an `ImmutableList`, and any code that does so is broken. If you need an `ImmutableList` from an `ImmutableCollection` use [`.asList()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html#asList--) - for most immutable collections this can return a view in O(1) time and space.

Comment: Thanks dimo.  ImmutableList.copyOf() answered technical problem here. Commit messages in links tells the rest.